# Can't call fetch api multiple times

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch, typeerror

I want to call this api multiple times in my project and when I am calling it , It continues giving an error which is

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': body stream already
> read at main.js:`Line number`

**My Code is as Follows**

```
let thisIsUrl = 'https://api.covid19api.com/summary';
let a = fetch(thisIsUrl)
a.then((data) => {
    return data.json()
}).then((apidata) => {
    console.log(apidata)
    return apidata
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
})


a.then((fetchdata) => {
    return fetchdata.json()
}).then((readingData) => {
    console.log(readingData)
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're assigning the result of `fetch` to a variable? I mean why don't you just use a new `fetch` instance every time? `fetch(thisIsUrl).then((data)...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're *not* calling `fetch` multiple times. You're calling it *once*, and then trying to read the response body multiple times. That's why the error says you're trying to read the body when the stream is already closed — it was closed when you were done reading it the first time.

If you want to use the data twice, store it somewhere and use it twice.

```
let thisIsUrl = 'https://api.covid19api.com/summary';
let a = fetch(thisIsUrl)
a.then((data) => {
    return data.json()
}).then((apidata) => {
    // **************** Use it twice here
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
})
```

If you want to fetch it again because it may have been updated, call `fetch` again:

```
let thisIsUrl = 'https://api.covid19api.com/summary';
fetch(thisIsUrl)
.then((data) => {
    return data.json();
}).then((apidata) => {
    console.log(apidata);
    return apidata;
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});


// Presumably this is later (in time), not immediately after the above
fetch(thisIsUrl)
.then((fetchdata) => {
    return fetchdata.json();
}).then((readingData) => {
    console.log(readingData);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Finally, this seems unlikely, but if you really want to fetch it once and use that one result in multiple places via the promise chain, keep the promise from `then` rather than the promise from `fetch`:

```
let thisIsUrl = 'https://api.covid19api.com/summary';
let a = fetch(thisIsUrl)
.then((data) => {
    return data.json()
});
a.then((apidata) => {
    // ***** Use it here
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
})

a.then((readingData) => {
    // ***** And then again here
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

---

Side note: Your code is falling prey to a footgun in the `fetch` API; I've written about it in [this blog post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html). `fetch` only rejects its promise on *network* errors, not HTTP errors. You have to check for those yourself in the first fulfillment handler, by checking for `ok` on the response object:

```
fetch("/your/resource")
.then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status); // Or better, use an Error subclass
    }
    return response.json();
})
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` returns `Promise`, generally, promises have something like state inside themself;

1. `pending`: initial state, neither fulfilled nor rejected.
2. `fulfilled`: meaning that the operation was completed successfully.
3. `rejected`: meaning that the operation failed.

([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Description))

So when we call them and get the value from them with `then`, `catch` and etc. then they change the state after that call. So here, when you read the value with `a.then(…`, the promise changes its state to `fulfilled` and you are not able to call it again, you need a new and fresh Promise, actually a new instance of the `fetch`.

Answer (score 0):

I want to recommend you to use Promise.all().

```
let thisIsUrl = 'https://api.covid19api.com/summary';
let a = fetch(thisIsUrl)
.then((data) => {
    return data.json()
}).then((apidata) => {
    console.log(apidata)
    return apidata
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
})

Promise.all([a,a,a]);
.then(results => {
     // Results are here.
});
```